# How to get average over time only when PC is up in Prometheus

Tags: wmi, grafana, prometheus, prometheus-node-exporter

I'm currently trying to get the average amount of free RAM in the last week on a Windows PC, using the WMI Exporter (https://github.com/martinlindhe/wmi_exporter) and Prometheus with the following query :

```
avg_over_time(wmi_os_physical_memory_free_bytes{instance="foo"}[1w])
```

The query inside "avg_over_time" is working correctly, but the problem is the PC is not up 24/7. Since I can't have holes in a range, I was considering the idea of using a recording rules.

The other problem is that the PC doesn't start and stop at known values, so I can't use the following solution : [How to get the average over time only during the day in Prometheus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53059856/how-to-get-the-average-over-time-only-during-the-day-in-prometheus/53066552#53066552) because I can't tell the time of the day I need to start collecting.

Is there any recording rule that could concatenate all the information gathered only during the up time of the pc ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above expression already does what you want, as there'll be no data for the periods when the target couldn't be scraped and `avg_over_time` doesn't try to do anything fancy with gaps.